# SX1272 bad performance

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, qucs

I want to use one shared antenna for the Lora/FSK transceiver sx1272 and LTE/GSM SIM700E module, with [BGS12SN6](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BGS12SN6-DS-v02_03-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433f1b26e8013f2db58bc03856) as a switch.

I've matched the antenna with two conductor and validated the result with a VNA after the switch (sx1272/SIM7000E->Switch->**TestPoint**->Matching->Antenna) with a reasonable performance (-28.9db 50.5+j0.17 @868MHz).

I strictly copied the [switchless reference design](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001NNb/CcLmIvttsaICaBS6YAyOPgwd5Hj84Kwm0ei890X76dc?__hstc=212684107.030493d62057d8ed2185f67ae2fbebdf.1635868041400.1646735905645.1646763665861.21&__hssc=212684107.2.1646763665861&__hsfp=772436748) from Semtech, but for some reason I get really a bad performance, even if I use an external 30db perfectly matched 50ohm antenna. I've already used the antenna for an other board with a Si4463 and get way better results (testing with wireless M-Bus devices, the Si4463 gets about 800 devices in the areas, the Sx1272 only about 150)

So I got curious and tried to rebuild the reference design with qucs (see image below (red line antenna without filter, blue line with reference design filter), but i don't think the result can be right.

[image: ReferenceDesign with matching]

The PCB schematic looks like the image below, the VNA was connected to J5, with C9 placed and C30 left open.
[image: PCBSchematic]

Is there anything I missed or did a big mistake? I'm grateful for any hint or idea.

Just in case I'm adding the application flow:
[image: AppFlow]

Comment: `the reference design is really bad` and `I rebuild the design with qucs and was a little shocked` are meaningless statements. They impart no technical value at all to help you with this: `Did I do something wrong?`. Then you say this: `I can't change the matching network because otherwise the GSM module would perform bad` but I'm unclear where it fits into things schematically.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I wanted to know if i did something wrong in qucs and get wrong results. `I can't change the matching network because otherwise the GSM module would perform bad` but i could change the values in the reference design, but i don't know what the sideeffects this would have.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer and added some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm now using the reference design with the antenna switch and now get good results.

After some searching and reading all kind of documentations I finally found out, the optimum match for the sx1272/1262/1232 is 28.5+j41.7 @ 915MHz (source: AN1200.16 of the SX1232). This explains my "wrong" qucs results. Unfortunately I couldn't find the optimum match at 868MHz.

[image]